# SQL XML generating multiple containers depending on row count

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

This is a bit of a difficult one to explain......but I'll do my best.....

I have a SQL XML export that works perfectly well however I need to add an additional field to record a wav file location. This wouldn't be a problem if there was only one wav location, however there could be either one or several wav locations that need recording.

Within my extract SQL I want to do something akin to a If statement or a Case When so when there is only one file location I only have the one XML container file location in the XML file, if there are two - I have two etc. I basically don't want empty containers. Does anybody know if this would be possible?

I have attached an example of code that hopefully give you an idea of what I'm asking.

(SELECT --Agreement--
'Some Text' as AdditionalInformation,

```
If @RecordingCount = 2  
    (SELECT 
            (Select 
                REC1.Recording_Location as MainRecordingRef
                FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRef'), TYPE),
            (Select
                REC1.Recording_Location as MainRecordingRef
                FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRef'), TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRefs'), TYPE),
End

If @RecordingCount = 3  
    (SELECT 
            (Select 
                REC1.Recording_Location as MainRecordingRef
                FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRef'), TYPE),
            (Select
                REC1.Recording_Location as MainRecordingRef
                FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRef'), TYPE),
                (Select
                REC1.Recording_Location as MainRecordingRef
                FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRef'), TYPE)
        FOR XML PATH('MainRecordingRefs'), TYPE),
End
```

FOR XML PATH('Agreement'), TYPE)

The above code doesn't work but was wondering if there was a different approach that I might need to take. Any advice would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

This is what I currently output...

`Agreement
AgreementReference PP20170510-122300 AgreementReference
  MainRecordingRefs
   MainRecordingRef
    RecRef LOGOS-PP20170510-122300-9174.wav /RecRef
   /MainRecordingRef
   MainRecordingRef 
    RecRef LOGOS-PP20170510-122400-9175.wav /RecRef
   /MainRecordingRef
  MainRecordingRef
  MainRecordingRef
  MainRecordingRef
  MainRecordingRefs
Agreement`

In the above I'm exporting five Recording Refs two have something in and the other three are empty but really only want to export the recording refs that are not empty so it looks something like...

`Agreement
AgreementReference PP20170510-122300 AgreementReference
  MainRecordingRefs
   MainRecordingRef
    RecRef LOGOS-PP20170510-122300-9174.wav /RecRef
   /MainRecordingRef
   MainRecordingRef
    RecRef LOGOS-PP20170510-122400-9175.wav /RecRef
   /MainRecordingRef
  MainRecordingRefs
Agreement`

Is there anything I can do within the XML to only show recording references that are not null?

Comment: Can you post some example data and your expected XML output please?

Comment: Hi Dave, this is not clear to me... Look at my answer. In the first lines you see an example how to create some *mockup-tables* with data. Try to do this for your real structure. Use the edit option to put this into your question. Show the expected output you want to get out of the data provided. Then place a comment with `@Shnugo` in it, and I'll come back soon (or somebody else...).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not quite clear (sample data + expected output would help most). But my magic crystall ball tells me, that you want to place one Wav into your XML and more Wavs - if there are any - into a further node collection...

Something like this?

```
DECLARE @mockup1 TABLE(ID INT,SomeData VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup1 VALUES (1,'Some 1 has 1 WAV')
                           ,(2,'Some 2 has 2 WAVs')
                           ,(3,'Some 3 has 3 WAVs');
DECLARE @mockup2 TABLE(ID INT,ID1 INT,WavUrl VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup2 VALUES(1,1,'URL 1')
                          ,(2,2,'URL 2-1')
                          ,(3,2,'URL 2-2')
                          ,(4,3,'URL 3-1')
                          ,(5,3,'URL 3-2')
                          ,(6,3,'URL 3-3');

SELECT m1.ID
      ,m1.SomeData
      --The first Wav goes in one extra node
      ,(SELECT w.ID
              ,w.WavUrl
        FROM @mockup2 AS w 
        WHERE w.ID1=m1.ID AND w.ID=(SELECT MIN(x.ID) FROM @mockup2 AS x WHERE x.ID1=m1.ID)
        FOR XML PATH('MainRecord'),TYPE
       )
      --All later Wavs go into a collection
      ,(SELECT w2.ID
              ,w2.WavUrl
        FROM @mockup2 AS w2
        WHERE w2.ID1=m1.ID AND w2.ID<>(SELECT MIN(x.ID) FROM @mockup2 AS x WHERE x.ID1=m1.ID)
        FOR XML PATH('Record'),ROOT('MoreRecords'),TYPE
        )
FROM @mockup1 AS m1
FOR XML PATH('Test'),ROOT('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <Test>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <SomeData>Some 1 has 1 WAV</SomeData>
    <MainRecord>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <WavUrl>URL 1</WavUrl>
    </MainRecord>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <SomeData>Some 2 has 2 WAVs</SomeData>
    <MainRecord>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <WavUrl>URL 2-1</WavUrl>
    </MainRecord>
    <MoreRecords>
      <Record>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <WavUrl>URL 2-2</WavUrl>
      </Record>
    </MoreRecords>
  </Test>
  <Test>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <SomeData>Some 3 has 3 WAVs</SomeData>
    <MainRecord>
      <ID>4</ID>
      <WavUrl>URL 3-1</WavUrl>
    </MainRecord>
    <MoreRecords>
      <Record>
        <ID>5</ID>
        <WavUrl>URL 3-2</WavUrl>
      </Record>
      <Record>
        <ID>6</ID>
        <WavUrl>URL 3-3</WavUrl>
      </Record>
    </MoreRecords>
  </Test>
</root>
```